# Inconsistent time measurements in c++ and bash script

Tags: c++, bash, c++-chrono

I have a large c++ program. I am using chrono to measure time.

```
auto begin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

//Do lot of computation here 

auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto dur = end - begin;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double> double_seconds;   
auto secs = std::chrono::duration_cast<double_seconds>(dur);
cout << argv[1] << " " << argv[2] << " " << fixed <<secs.count() << "s" << endl;
```

The amount of computation depends on argv[1], higher argv[1] means more computation.

The time for argv[1] = 12 comes out to : 0.001969s

Now i write a shellscript with multiple argv[1]'s

```
vertices=(12 14 16)
edgefactors=(16)
printf "mBallStringinc\n" 
for vertex in ${vertices[*]}
do
   for edgefactor in ${edgefactors[*]}
   do
        ./mBallStringinc ${vertex} ${edgefactor}
   done
done
```

If i run this shell script the time for argv[1]=12 comes out to be 0.0000014s

I don't understand how this is possible, i noticed the same behaviour for multiple argv[1]'s

Somehow executing the program within a for loop in a shell script reduces the time drastically.

Comment: The times you measure are extremely small, so stuff like loading the binary to RAM or finding shared libraries (stuff that can probably be cached when looped) might dominate. Use an input that takes a couple of seconds to complete and see if the difference gets negligible.

Comment: Also take into account that the OS probably does some kind of optimization (including reading the program from disk to RAM). So, if you repeat a program lots of times, you will see a drastic reduction in runtime. This is also true of simple executables like mv $file_inp $file_out.

Comment: Not on topic, but here's a simpler way to construct secs:  `double_seconds secs = end - begin;`

Comment: First of all, note that output to file is way faster than output to console. However, wrong output is your program's fault, the bash does not skip anything. So I'm afraid you'll have to debug that yourself. Look for UB like uninitialized variables.